# Error in subquery

Tags: mysql

im stuck here and i don't know how to fix it.

I have a db table which has users ID, user grade and date when someone has voted for that user (3 fields).

Im trying to read the user that has the highest average grade for todays date, limited to one.
But the problem is that i want to read only users that have 5 or more votes.

My query looks like this, but im getting an error:

```
  SELECT 
   idusers,
   AVG(votes) AS Grade
  FROM rank
  WHERE (data = '{$dbDate}') 
    AND ((SELECT count(ID) + 1 FROM rank) AS tmpcount WHERE tmpcount>4)
  GROUP BY idusers
  ORDER BY Grade DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Without the `tmpcount>4` clause this query is working ok, but I need to count the Id's.

Comment: Please choose a better title for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to filter the result set on aggregated values such as `COUNT` (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, …):

```
SELECT idusers, AVG(votes) AS Grade
FROM rank
WHERE (data = '{$dbDate}')
GROUP BY idusers
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
ORDER BY Grade DESC
LIMIT 1
```